# Bootstrap - How to not open sub menu with click

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap with wordpress `wp_nav_menu` and i don't want to show dropdown menu on click, just with hover but i don't know how can i do that.

Anyone can help me?

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The menu is generated by this code:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'              => 'menuPrincipal',
    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
    'depth'             => 2,
    'container'         => 'div',
    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
);
```

?>

Thank you

Comment: Seems to work fine https://www.bootply.com/8BPPcN0lsB

Comment: working fine...

Comment: Just remove `data-toggle="dropdown"`

Comment: ok, but how can i remove data-toggle if i'm using wp_nav_menu? @APAD1

Comment: i update the question @APAD1

Comment: Show us the code for `wp_bootstrap_navwalker()`

Comment: I go to wp_bootstrap_navwalker() file and comment the line about data-toggle and works. thank you @APAD1

Comment: @user3242861 you are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu
{
  display: block;
}
```

Try this:

```
li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

The angle bracket ensures that hover is directed to the correct (first) child element.